# Replace elements in list and sort the list

Tags: python, list

I have 2 list

```
a=[2,4,6]
b=[1,3,5,-1,-1,-1]
```

I have to replace the `-1` in `b` with elements from list `a` and then print `b` as a sorted list

Expected

```
output= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: if you sort the list at the end anyways, why are you worrying about replacing the `-1`s? Does just removing them entirely work?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a=[2,4,6]
b=[1,3,5,-1,-1,-1]
a.reverse()

for i,v in enumerate(b):
    if v == -1:
        b[i] = a.pop()
```

Then you can sort `b` as you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can do with a list-comprehension and calling `sorted()` on it:

```
a = [2,4,6]
b = [1,3,5,-1,-1,-1]

a = iter(a)
output = sorted([next(a) if x == -1 else x for x in b])

print(output)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Excellent answer, +1, but this has the side-effect of changing `a` from a list to an exhausted iterator. Perhaps you should use another name for the iterator?

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I'm not sure if OP has plans on using `a` further. If yes, sure needs to be named a different iterator.

Comment: Thanks this works great. I learnt a new  function: next..thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in a:
      b[b.index(-1)]=i
    b.sort()
```

The above is all it needs for your requirement

Comment: You can keep `b.sort()` outside loop, so it doesn't sort in every iteration.

Comment: I added. This snippet from phone. That's what I intended to do

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise the `list.pop()` method to get the next item from `b` whilst also removing it and then wrap the whole list comprehension in `sorted()`:

```
a = [2,4,6]
b = [1,3,5,-1,-1,-1]


a = sorted([b.pop(0) if i == -1 else i
            for i in a]
```

However, if you want to keep list `b`, you’re better off using `next()` on `iter(a)` as written in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This verbose option works also if `-1`'s are more than `len(a`):

```
a=[2,4,6]
b=[1,3,5,-1,-1,-1,-1]

def replace(iterable, replacements):
  i = 0
  for e in iterable:
    if e == -1 and i < len(replacements):
      yield replacements[i]
      i += 1
    else:
      yield e

res = sorted(replace(b, a))

print(res) #=> [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```